# How add custom fileld to custom article listing page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type. I am trying to display each 
post click and views counts in custom articles listing page (see screenshot), but no success.

[image]

Comment: do you met case similar to this? @LoicTheAztec

Comment: I think you should provide more details. What you have done to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it like this.  You will need to adjust for your post types and field names.  In this example I will use the post type of 'custom-articale' and field name of 'view-count'.

```
add_filter('manage_custom-articale_posts_columns', 'reveal_view_count', 1);
add_action('manage_custom-articale_posts_custom_column', 'reveal_view_count_value', 1, 2);

function reveal_view_count($columns)
{
    $columns['view-count'] = 'View Count';
    return $columns;
}

function reveal_view_count_value($column)
{
    if ('view-count' == $column) {
        echo the_field('view-count');
    }
}
```